# My image in ImageView glitches for a second

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I'm using Xcode 5.1.1

When i click the BACK button from ViewController 1 to ViewController 2, and when VC 1 appears the ImageView glitches for 1 second before going back to normal. I tried programming the segue with performSegueWithIdentifier but that didn't solve the issue. I tried using Modal's cross dissolve transition, cover vertical and partial cross but they don't help the glitch either. Only Flip Horizontal doesn't have the glitch but it wouldn't look good with my app. I'm currently using unwind segue to go from VC 2 to VC 1 but the VC 1 is glitching for 1 second. I tried regular modal but that creates worse problems. What do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should admit that "The UIImageView" is quite a generic assumption to figure out what your issue actually is. Just for pure diagnosis purpose I'd do the following checks:

- Check the size of your UIImage you're assigning to the UIImageView. If the UIImage is too big the higher resolution might cause some rendering problem in the animations.
- To have a proper check of what's going on you might want to run instruments adding "Time Profiler" to your tab. Performing either the pop or dismiss of your VC2 you should be able to figure out where the glitch comes from.

I know it's quite a generic answer but with the little info you provided don't think anyone might be able to help you more than that.

Hope this helps.